# how to calculate total PHP dateInterval and show result in date,month,year

Tags: php, datetime

I have many PHP DateInterval variables. 
example :

```
//code
$dateInterval1 = startDate1->diff(endDate1);
$dateInterval2 = startDate2->diff(endDate2);
$dateInterval3 = startDate3->diff(endDate3);

//result in dateInterval1, dateInterval2, dateInterval3 
$dateInterval1 = DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 1
    [m] => 5
    [d] => 18
)

$dateInterval2 = DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 2
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 30
)

$dateInterval3 = DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 3
    [d] => 2
)
```

I want to find total of dateInterval (dateInterval1+dateInterval2+dateInterval3).

With the specifications as

1. 'startDate1' in begin day. and 'endDate3' in final day isn't continuous.

And Show result in format  %d days, %m months %y years As humans understand.

How do I  do?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself into solving this?

Comment: I find and get an answer, it take the timestamp of the date, the end date minus the timestamp of the start date, to get the desired timestamp answer.

Comment: After that add it together. Will get the result
But the problem is that when converted to days, months, years, it is given more than 73 years, which is not what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DateInterval objects were created in a similar fashion to below then you can add the constituent parts and re-formulate a new `DateInterval` with the summed values

```
$p1=new DateInterval('P1Y5M18D');
$p2=new DateInterval('P2Y0M30D');
$p3=new DateInterval('P0Y3M2D');

$yr=$p1->y + $p2->y + $p3->y;
$mo=$p1->m + $p2->m + $p3->m;
$dy=$p1->d + $p2->d + $p3->d;

$exp=sprintf('P%dY%dM%dD',$yr,$mo,$dy);

$out=new DateInterval( $exp );

echo $out->format('%d days %m months %Y years');
```

outputs

```
50 days 8 months 03 years
```

Comment: What can I do with 50 days?

In fact, if more than 30 days are considered 1 month and 12 months are considered 1 year, so the answer here is that it should be 20 days, 9 months, 3 years.

Comment: I guess that depends upon the month and thus the number of days in the month - considering that this does what was asked  it is now a somewhat different criteria than posed in the question would you not agree?!

Comment: I think I posted the question is not clear. Resulting in a different answer than I thought. But your code is useful That I can use PHP DateInterval to do many things. And it is also my learning. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You need a reference date to have valid numbers for days and months.

```
$di = [
  new DateInterval('P1Y5M18D'),
  new DateInterval('P2Y0M30D'),
  new DateInterval('P0Y3M2D')
];

$referenceDate = date_create("2000-01-01");

$curDate = clone $referenceDate;
foreach($di as $curDi){
  $curDate->add($curDi);
}
$sum = $referenceDate->diff($curDate);

echo $sum->y.' Years and '.$sum->m.' Month and '.$sum->d.' Days';
```

output:

```
3 Years and 9 Month and 19 Days
```

With different reference dates you also have different results because the months have different numbers of days.

With Reference Date 2019-03-01 you get "3 Years and 9 Month and 21 Days" !